# cucumber load error activesupport

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bundler, activesupport, gemfile

I am new to rails and I having trouble using cucumber to run my tests.  I get the following error:

```
You have already activated activesupport 3.1.0, but your Gemfile requires activesupport 3.1.0.rc8. Consider using bundle exec. (Gem::LoadError)
```

and my gemfile looks like the following:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc8'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "  ~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem "therubyracer", ">= 0.8.2"
gem "haml", ">= 3.1.2"
gem "haml-rails", ">= 0.3.4", :group => :development
gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.6.1", :group => [:development, :test]
gem "guard-rspec"
gem "database_cleaner", ">= 0.6.7", :group => :test
gem "mongoid-rspec", ">= 1.4.4", :group => :test
gem "factory_girl_rails", ">= 1.1.0", :group => :test
gem "cucumber-rails", ">= 1.0.2", :group => :test
gem "capybara", ">= 1.0.1", :group => :test
gem "launchy", ">= 2.0.5", :group => :test
gem "bson_ext", ">= 1.3.1"
gem "mongoid", ">= 2.1.9"
gem 'devise', :git => 'git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git', :branch => 'master'
gem "frontend-helpers"
gem "rails-footnotes", ">= 3.7", :group => :development
gem "barista"
gem "sunspot"
gem 'sunspot_rails'
gem "sunspot_mongoid"
gem 'vinova_sunspot_mongoid', :require => 'sunspot_mongoid'
gem "fakeweb", "~> 1.3.0"
gem "sunspot_matchers", "~> 1.2.1.4"
```

Cucumber used to work before. I recently added sunspot and upgraded to rails 3.1.0.rc8. I don't understand bundle exec message.

thanks

Comment: have you tried to run cucumber using bundler?

Comment: tried 'bundler exec cucumber features' and it worked but why can't I run it from the command 'cucumber features' anymore?

Comment: Because you have more than one version of rails installed on your machine. It's a problem of dependencies that's exactly what bundler solves :D

Comment: @lucapette You should probably post this as an answer, so this thread can be closed. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
bundler exec cucumber features
```

It should work fine. Please see [docs](http://gembundler.com/rationale.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

This what worked for me:

```
bundle exec cucumber features

bundle exec cucumber features/filter_movie_list.feature
```

The first one for all features, and the second one for certain feature.